# Can we create a Java variable with : operator?

Tags: java, variables, jaxb, syntax-error

Is ther any way to declare variable like this:

```
private String xmlns:xsi;
```

Resulting into the following error:

```
Syntax error on token ":", , expected
```

But, I want to have **':'** in my variable name. It is mandatory.

*It is mandatory because I am using jaxb api to unmarshal my xml file to Java. In the XML I have an element with attribute named xmlns:xsi. Now, in the POJO I have to use this attribute as a variable to store the value. That's why it is mandatory for me to have the variable name like this.*

Comment: ':' is not a legal sign for java variables. Why is it mandatory?

Comment: @Juan I am using jaxb api to unmarshal my xml file to Java. In the XML I have an element with attribute named **xmlns:xsi**. Now, in the POJO I have to use this attribute as a variable to store the value. That's why it is mandatory for me to have the variable name like this

Comment: see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8

Comment: An attribute like that is a declaration of a namespace. It's usually not something that should be present in the object. You should probably look into namespace handling in JAXB instead.

Answer (score 2):

Every programming language has its own set of rules and conventions for the kinds of names that you're allowed to use, and the Java programming language is no different. The rules and conventions for naming your variables can be summarized as follows:

- Variable names are case-sensitive. A variable's name can be any legal identifier — an unlimited-length sequence of Unicode letters and digits, beginning with a letter, the dollar sign "$", or the underscore character "*". The convention, however, is to always begin your variable names with a letter, not "$" or "*". Additionally, the dollar sign character, by convention, is never used at all. You may find some situations where auto-generated names will contain the dollar sign, but your variable names should always avoid using it. A similar convention exists for the underscore character; while it's technically legal to begin your variable's name with "_", this practice is discouraged. White space is not permitted.
- Subsequent characters may be letters, digits, dollar signs, or underscore characters. Conventions (and common sense) apply to this rule as well. When choosing a name for your variables, use full words instead of cryptic abbreviations. Doing so will make your code easier to read and understand. In many cases it will also make your code self-documenting; fields named cadence, speed, and gear, for example, are much more intuitive than abbreviated versions, such as s, c, and g. Also keep in mind that the name you choose must not be a keyword or reserved word.
- If the name you choose consists of only one word, spell that word in all lowercase letters. If it consists of more than one word, capitalize the first letter of each subsequent word. The names gearRatio and currentGear are prime examples of this convention. If your variable stores a constant value, such as static final int NUM_GEARS = 6, the convention changes slightly, capitalizing every letter and separating subsequent words with the underscore character. By convention, the underscore character is never used elsewhere.

via : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html

Edit: Another way if you really want to do it.

If you really need to map string values on a particular variable. 
You can use HASH MAP

```
 Map<String,String> stringMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
 stringMap .put("xmlns:xsi", "variableValue");
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't create the variable containing : character, please refer below document:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html

> Variable names are case-sensitive. A variable's name can be any legal
>   identifier — an unlimited-length sequence of Unicode letters and
>   digits, beginning with a letter, the dollar sign "$", or the
>   underscore character "*". The convention, however, is to always begin
>   your variable names with a letter, not "$" or "*". Additionally, the
>   dollar sign character, by convention, is never used at all. You may
>   find some situations where auto-generated names will contain the
>   dollar sign, but your variable names should always avoid using it. A
>   similar convention exists for the underscore character; while it's
>   technically legal to begin your variable's name with "_", this
>   practice is discouraged. White space is not permitted. Subsequent
>   characters may be letters, digits, dollar signs, or underscore
>   characters. Conventions (and common sense) apply to this rule as well.
>   When choosing a name for your variables, use full words instead of
>   cryptic abbreviations. Doing so will make your code easier to read and
>   understand. In many cases it will also make your code
>   self-documenting; fields named cadence, speed, and gear, for example,
>   are much more intuitive than abbreviated versions, such as s, c, and
>   g. Also keep in mind that the name you choose must not be a keyword or
>   reserved word. If the name you choose consists of only one word, spell
>   that word in all lowercase letters. If it consists of more than one
>   word, capitalize the first letter of each subsequent word. The names
>   gearRatio and currentGear are prime examples of this convention. If
>   your variable stores a constant value, such as static final int
>   NUM_GEARS = 6, the convention changes slightly, capitalizing every
>   letter and separating subsequent words with the underscore character.
>   By convention, the underscore character is never used elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

No, **:** is not a legal character in a Java identifer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the `:` character in variable names. Variable names don't exist at runtime anyway, so there would be no benefit to giving it such a name.

If you want to use the string `xmlns:xsi` to refer to a value, use a Map.

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("xmlns:xsi", "foo");
```

Comment: "Variable names don't exist at runtime anyway" - I bet `jaxb` and other frameworks disagree with that.